# QTableView won't display single line of text quite right

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview

Here's an MRE:

```
import sys, logging, datetime

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import QVBoxLayout

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__class__.instance = self
        self.resize(1200, 1600) # w, h
        main_splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self)
        main_splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_splitter)
        self.top_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        main_splitter.addWidget(self.top_frame)
        self.bottom_frame = BottomFrame()
        self.bottom_frame.setMaximumHeight(350)                
        self.bottom_frame.setMinimumHeight(100)
        main_splitter.addWidget(self.bottom_frame)
        main_splitter.setCollapsible(1, False)
        self.bottom_frame.construct()
            
class BottomFrame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def construct(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        # without this you get the default 10 px border all round the table: too much
        layout.setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.messages_table = LogTableView()
        layout.addWidget(self.messages_table)
        self.messages_table.visual_log('hello world')                
        self.messages_table.visual_log('message 2 qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd ')
        self.messages_table.visual_log('message 3')
        self.messages_table.visual_log('message 4', logging.ERROR)
        self.messages_table.visual_log('message 5')
        self.messages_table.visual_log('message 6 qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd qunaomdd ')
        self.messages_table.visual_log('message 7')
        
class LogTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel())
        self.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.setVerticalHeader(VerticalHeader(self))
        self.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        # this doesn't seem to have any effect 
        # self.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(1)
        
    def sizeHintForRow(self, row ):
        hint = super().sizeHintForRow(row)
        # print(f'size hint for row {row}: {hint}')
        # this doesn't seem to have any effect!
        if hint < 25 and hint > 10: 
            hint = 10
        return hint
        
    def visual_log(self, msg: str, log_level: int=logging.INFO):
        model = self.model()
        i_new_row = model.rowCount()
        model.insertRow(i_new_row)
        datetime_stamp_str = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%a %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
        model.setItem(i_new_row, 0, QtGui.QStandardItem(datetime_stamp_str))
        model.setItem(i_new_row, 1, QtGui.QStandardItem(str(log_level)))
        self.setColumnWidth(0, 160)
        self.setColumnWidth(1, 100)
        model.setItem(i_new_row, 2, QtGui.QStandardItem(msg))
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.resizeRowsToContents)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10, self.scrollToBottom)
            
class VerticalHeader(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(QtCore.Qt.Vertical, parent)
    
    def sectionSizeHint(self, logical_index):
        hint = super().sectionSizeHint(logical_index)
        print(f'vh index {logical_index} hint {hint}')
        return hint

def main():
    app_instance = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow().show()  
    sys.exit(app_instance.exec())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In terms of row heights it's *ALMOST* doing what I want: try resizing the main window: the table rows adjust their heights depending on the real height of the text (wrapped as needed).

BUT... while this works if you have a piece of text which needs more than one row, sizing the row height just right, the single-line rows always take up slightly too much height. The `sizeHintForRow()` method of the `QTableView` always seems to return 24 (pixels) from the superclass ... but even if I interfere with that and brutally say "no, make it a smaller hint", it appears that that gets overridden by something later.

`setMinimumSectionSize` on the vertical header also seems to have no effect.

I also thought the `data()` method of the table model might be the culprit but role 13, "SizeHintRole", never seems to get fired.

**Source code**
I have tried looking at the [source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qheaderview.cpp?h=dev). The method of interest here seems to be on l. 3523, one of several versions of `QHeaderView`'s `resizeSections` method. The code is naturally quite daunting, but I did spot, for example, `invalidateCachedSizeHint()` on l. 3261, which might explain why the size hints are being ignored... Anyone with particularly intricate knowledge of `QHeaderView`'s functionality? ***Update later*** After Musicamante suggested use of `setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContent)` (good idea), I don't now know what part of the source code is involved.

**Screenshot**
[image: main window]

... the single-text-line rows are slightly too high. If you see something different, like perfectly tight single-text-line rows, please let me know. I'm on W10. A different OS may produce a different result, who knows?

Comment: Why don't you use `setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)` for the vertical header? Also, please provide a more appropriate [mre], as lots of your code is completely irrelevant to the issue (for instance, the whole model implementation, the delayed UI initialization, etc.) and it's just extremely distracting.

Comment: Thanks. Strange, `self.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)` seems to be causing a non-catchable crash. I'll try to make a more minimal thing. But I don't know for sure that the model doesn't play a part...

Comment: IDEs aren't always able to show full tracebacks, especially when dealing with bindings: run your code in a terminal or prompt. The error is probably caused by the fact that you're calling `itemFromIndex()` in `data()`, but `data()` may be called even for indexes that have no QStandardItem set yet, which would then return `None`. In any case, since you're only returning slightly different values in `data()` and none of them actually affects row sizes directly, it certainly is not caused by that; besides, just you just need to try it.

Comment: Thanks. I've done a much cleaner MRE. (I've added the possibility of a superclass for the vertical header, because that source code method seems to use the QHeaderView method `sectionSizeHint` ... but with this MRE this isn't being called). That crash isn't happening any more, no doubt because I got rid of the table model class.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion automates the behaviour of row resize. Great stuff, thanks. But the row height problem is still there.

Comment: You're calling `setSectionResizeMode()` on the *current* header, but then you immediately substitute it. Move that line *after* setting the new header (or set that in the `__init__` of the subclass. If you still have issues with vertical margins, please provide a screenshot of what you see, as I cannot reproduce it. Also, avoid generic stylesheets, especially in containers (as you did for `bottom_frame` and `top_frame`): always use proper [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types), or you'll have propagation problems with complex widgets like scroll areas.

Comment: Sorry, I did spot that after posting the MRE. Updated. What's odd is that neither `VerticalHeader.resizeSection(...)` nor `VerticalHeader.resizeSections(...)` ever seems to be called. Quite puzzled about how to find what's going on in the source code.

Comment: `resizeSection()` and `resizeSections()` are not virtual, overriding them is pointless. I cannot see any issue when resizing the window, the text is properly wrapped and aligned within the item geometry. Can you please provide a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Added screenshot. Hopefully you can see that the single-line-text rows are slightly too high. I'm on W10: what OS are you on? Should we move to chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is twofold, as resizing to contents means that the header queries its own size requirements and the view's:

- the header's `defaultSectionSize()`, `minimumSectionSize()` and `sectionSizeFromContents()`;
- the view's `sizeHintForRow()` (or `sizeHintForColumn()` for horizontal headers), which eventually queries the delegate's `sizeHint()` function;

When the view only shows one line, the style (which is what the header functions above query) returns default heights, which may have larger vertical margins above and beyond the displayed text.

When word wrap is enabled and more than one line is shown, the displayed text normally requires more vertical space than the header would eventually use, and that space is increased by a default margin that may result in a smaller visual margin than in single line mode.

In order to achieve consistent resizing, you have to implement a custom header that always returns a very small size from `sectionSizeFromContents`, and arbitrary small sizes should be set as well for both the `defaultSectionSize` and `minimumSectionSize`. In this way, the view will always consider the actual contents of the displayed text, and the margins will always be consistent.

```py
class VerticalHeader(QHeaderView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(Qt.Vertical, parent)
        # we can set everything in here
        self.setSectionResizeMode(self.ResizeToContents)
        self.setDefaultSectionSize(1)
        self.setMinimumSectionSize(1)
        self.hide()

    def sectionSizeFromContents(self, index):
        size = super().sectionSizeFromContents(index)
        size.setHeight(1)
        return size
```

<sup>Note that `sectionSizeFromContents()` is also used to get the width of a vertical header, but since you're not displaying the vertical header, a simpler `return QSize()` would suffice.</sup>

Finally, you just need to properly set up the header; you do not need to override `sizeHintForRow` in the table anymore, but further changes should be considered:

```py
class LogTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # IMPORTANT! set the column count, so that we can automatically set 
        # the column widths
        self.setModel(QStandardItemModel(0, 3))
        self.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        self.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.setVerticalHeader(VerticalHeader(self))

        self.setColumnWidth(0, 160)
        self.setColumnWidth(1, 100)

    ...
```

As an unrelated note, you should avoid to convert numbers to strings if the program logic needs to use numerical values. Instead of doing `QStandardItem(str(log_level))`, use [`QStandardItem.setData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#setData); the delegate will automatically convert values to strings wherever necessary.

The same also goes for date/time values, as they might require proper logical implementation (for instance, sorting or filtering): you may just use a proper delegate in order to *display* the date according to your format.

```py
class DateDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def displayText(self, value, locale):
        if isinstance(value, QDateTime):
            return value.toString('ddd HH:mm:ss.zzz')
        return super().displayText(value, locale)


class LogTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ... # as above

        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, DateDelegate(self))

    def visual_log(self, msg: str, log_level: int=logging.INFO):
        model = self.model()
        i_new_row = model.rowCount()
        model.insertRow(i_new_row)

        datetime_item = QStandardItem()
        datetime_item.setData(QDateTime.currentDateTime(), Qt.DisplayRole)
        model.setItem(i_new_row, 0, datetime_item)

        log_item = QStandardItem()
        log_item.setData(log_level, Qt.DisplayRole)
        model.setItem(i_new_row, 1, log_item)

        model.setItem(i_new_row, 2, QStandardItem(msg))
```